# How can I map a Service's Keyboard Shortcut on the Command Line?

Tags: macos, keyboard, automator

I'm trying to write a program that adds some new services to the Mac.

For this to work I need to add keyboard shortcuts to some installed services. Doing it though system preferences is not an option.

I need a command line operation that will let me map a keyboard shortcut to user created service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service shortcuts are stored in pbs.plist and can be modified like this:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Delete NSServicesStatus:"(null) - \
  servicename - runWorkflowAsService"' ~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist 2>/dev/null
defaults write pbs NSServicesStatus -dict-add '"(null) - \
  servicename - runWorkflowAsService"' \
  '{key_equivalent = "^~@1";}'
```

<sup>Source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/3936/</sup>

`^` = control, `~` = alt, `@` = command; replace `servicename` with the name of the service